# Issue when writing file to disk after downloading it by FTP

Tags: go, ftp

The file that is written to disk is empty, but the reader is not.
I do not understand where the issue is.
I tried to play with a `Buffer` and then `String()` method and I can confirm that the content is fine, but using the `Read()` method of this library is not working.

The library I use is `github.com/jlaffaye/ftp`

```
// pullFileByFTP
func pullFileByFTP(fileID, server string, port int64, username, password, path, file string) error {
    // Connect to the server
    client, err := ftp.Dial(fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", server, port))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // Log in the server
    err = client.Login(username, password)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // Retrieve the file
    reader, err := client.Retr(fmt.Sprintf("%s%s", path, file))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // Read the file
    var srcFile []byte
    _, err = reader.Read(srcFile)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // Create the destination file
    dstFile, err := os.Create(fmt.Sprintf("%s/%s", shared.TmpDir, fileID))
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Error while creating the destination file : %s", err)
    }
    defer dstFile.Close()

    // Copy the file
    dstFile.Write(srcFile)

    return nil
}
```

Comment: What is the content of `srcFile` after `reader.Read`? Maybe you need a `reader.Close()` after `reader.Read`?

Comment: @RickyA : thanks for helping. It is an empty array. Let me try to Close()

Comment: @RickyA : Close() has no effect

Comment: The file is empty because `srcFile` is not yet allocated. There is nothing was readed. Instead of reading the content to slice/buffer, just use `io.Copy`.

Comment: Sorry but I am trying to use the methods that are provided by the library and it only gives me a Read() that is going to a []byte variable..

Comment: @putu : The response is a `*Response` type, I am not sure that I can use it in `io.Copy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [Read](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader) and [Write](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Writer) wrong:

```
var srcFile []byte
_, err = reader.Read(srcFile)
```

Read puts the read bytes into its argument. Since srcFile is a nil slice, this instructs the reader to read zero bytes. Use [ioutil.ReadAll](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadAll) to read all bytes.

Next up is your use of Write. `Write(b)` writes *up to* len(b) bytes, but not necessarily all of it. You must check the return values and call Write repeatedly if necessary.

However, in your case you just want to connect an io.Reader (*Response implements io.Reader) and io.Writer (*os.File). That's what [io.Copy](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Copy) is for:

```
reader, err := client.Retr(path + file)
dstFile, err := ioutil.TempFile("", fileID)

_, err := io.Copy(dstFile, reader)
err := dstFile.Close()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! `io.Copy` is doing the job. But for my personnal understanding, how did you notice that the `*Response` is a `io.Reader` ? With this information, I could had understood how to do it, but I thought the only way to use the response was with the provided `Read()` method..

Comment: @Elwyn, I simply recognized the method signature. One can also expect an FTP API to implement io.Reader and io.Writer. It would be ridiculous if it didn't, because Readers and Writers are *everywhere* in Go. This means you can plug things together like Legos. Have you perhaps not understood the [implicit nature of interfaces](https://tour.golang.org/methods/10) in Go yet?